# Porting WP App to Android with Cordova - pick folder

Tags: windows, cordova, directory, winjs, porting

I have found a [nice topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdn_answers/archive/2014/08/26/porting-a-windows-store-app-using-html-to-cordova.aspx) about porting WinJS Apps to Android ( and now can use WinJS ), but have not found any else information.
For example I want to use Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker(). As I have understand namespace Windows is missing. What should I use instead of?
Have no idea - could someone who knows Cordova well help? I'll write an article if I'll understand it)

Answer (score 1):

The Windows namespace is not a part of WinJS but a part of WinRT. So you cannot use it on android cordova project.

We have developed an abstraction layer to provide the same functions to access to multiple operations like reading / writing files / access to photo library, recording sounds regardless on WinRT or Cordova context. (namespace :  winjscontrib.datacontainer)

You can find in this project (https://github.com/gleborgne/winjscontrib)

Other explanations are here (but written in french :))

http://mcnextpost.com/2015/02/16/ecriturelecturemodification-de-fichiers-dans-un-projet-universel-app-et-cordova/

http://mcnextpost.com/2015/02/16/winjs-dans-une-application-cross-plateforme-cordova/

Comment: Thank you for answer! As I have understand I should use some else way to access file system on android. Your component is nice(!), but may be a lot not exactly what I'm searching. I wish to let user select folder and use files. In french example written about getting container by id or key. Try to take a look once again more closer